# How can i extract data from collection with many documents in talend?

Tags: talend

[JobTalend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNiN.jpg)[MyJob[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvG2C.jpg)I can extract only the simple fields, i used the component textractfieldjson but I find many problems to extract the others documents in talend

Comment: What did you try ? What kind of problems did you have ? Please add a screenshot of your job. We lack details to help you.

Comment: I want to extract ownerId and Filters so  my purpose is to have a collection with simple fields :/

Answer (score 0):

Wael Hichri,
You are looping filters field in textractjsonfield component, that means you will only get the contents of filters field values not their parent field value.

In the provided job, you are trying to access filters field parents value, which will not be able to get.

Comment: Thanks Revathi Daggu, i have to find a solution to get filters with their parents value, so do you know how can i get these information

Comment: Wael Hichri, please confirm one thing, is ownerId in Accordsid path ? If thats the case, 
Fetch filters path data along with _id (unique for every document) into one thashoutput, and fetch ownerId path data along with _id into another thashoutput2. Join both thashinput's data using _id as joining column to get the combined desired output.

Comment: Thanks Revathi Daggu for response but it didn't work, so do you can send me an example ?